# Problems testing Camel with Spring config

Tags: unit-testing, spring, apache-camel

I have a routes defined in `CamelRoutes.xml` and I would like to test them by using the wrapping technique described at the bottom of http://camel.apache.org/mock.html.

My `CamelRoutes.xml`

```
 <route autoStartup="true"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="direct:end"/>
    </route>
```

So I created `CamelRoutesTest.xml` containing:

```
<import resource="CamelRoutes.xml"/>
<bean id="mockAllEndpoints" class="org.apache.camel.impl.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy"/>
```

but I am not sure how to create a test that both loads the spring xml AND provides access to the mock endpoints.

If I use..

```
@ContextConfiguration( locations=("/CamelRoutesTest"))
public class CamelTest extends AbstractJUnit38SpringContextTests

}
```

then I have no idea how to *get* the mock endpoints

If I use..

```
public class CamelTest extends CamelTestSupport

}
```

then I dont know how to load my camel context..

I can't seem to find an example test on the website that uses `CamelTestSupport` AND loads routes from spring xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved using:

```
public class CamelTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport {  

    @Override
    protected AbstractXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext() {
        return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/CamelRoutesTest.xml");
    }

    @Test
    @DirtiesContext
    public void discover() throws Exception {

        getMockEndpoint("mock:my.route.out").expectedMessageCount(1);

        template.sendBody("direct:my.route.in", FileUtils.slurpClassPathFile("/samples/sample.data.xml"));

        assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tom you already posted this on the Camel mailing list. I suggest that you write this when you post a Q here as well.

The answer is already posted here
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Problems-testing-Camel-with-Spring-config-tp4267754p4267754.html

Comment: I normally update my question here if/when I get an answer elsewhere. At the moment I'm still lacking a decent example of how to properly mock my route so that my test's don't hit external systems.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for this solution, @Tom !

I also had a hard time getting Camel to work with my Spring-powered JUnit tests, problem is the suggested CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner has now moved from camel-spring.jar to a separate module, camel-spring-test.jar, which is not available in the standard camel-distribution as of 2.9.2.

So I cannot use @RunWith but had to resort to the manual method described in the solution...